# EKS service SSL endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks, aws-eks

When creating a `service` using EKS, it is exposed using http through a AWS load balancer.

`kubectl apply -f service.yaml` - Will create a load balancer that's managed by EKS, and can not be modified. any modification, valid or not will be overriden by AWS at some point.

I'm going down the rabbit hole of trying to expose the service as HTTPS.

Modifying the aws load balancer to listen on 443 in https with and acm certificate, will provide a temporary solution, which will be reset when EKS will refresh the load balancer back to 'factory settings'.

Best approach seems to be to create an `ingress` load balancer that can support HTTPS. following these articles:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/aws-load-balancer-controller.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/alb-ingress.html

`listen-ports` and `certificate-arn` were added to the ingress yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  namespace: game-2048
  name: ingress-2048
  annotations:
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: ip
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTP":80},{"HTTPS":443}]' # Added by me
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/certificate-arn: arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:411686525067:certificate/8adf7812-a1af-4eae-af1b-ea425a238a67

spec:
  ingressClassName: alb
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
        - path: /
          pathType: Prefix
          backend:
            service:
              name: service-2048
              port:
                number: 80
```

`EKS` will create an `ALB` with a host name such as: `k8s--------d4ees4dc9b-1296497080.eu-central-1.elb.amazonaws.com` which is under the `amazonaws.com`.

When adding to the yaml config, `certificate-arn` the ALB will be created with a port 443 listener, and will be attached the ACM certificate that was specified.

But, since the ALB host is under the `amazonaws.com` domain, the certificate mismatches and I'm back to square one.

How can I make EKS create an https ALB?

On a higher level, I manage DNS on `cloudflare` and will create a CNAME proxy record for `api.mydomain.com` to the ALB host `k8s--------d4ees4dc9b-1296497080.eu-central-1.elb.amazonaws.com`

For the DNS proxy to work well, both 'sides' must support https.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The configuration described in the question is all you need to get an `SSL endpoint`

Once configured with an ALB that listens on https/443 and  a proper `alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/certificate-arn` for your non aws `domain.com`.

a **proxy** CNAME record (cloudflare) from `domain.com` to `k8sd4ees4dc9b-1296497080.eu-central-1.elb.amazonaws.com` will enable connection to `domain.com` through the ALB with the valid SSL certification provided by the ALB.

connecting to the aws generating address using SSL will invoke the SSL mismatch warning, which is fine and as it should be.

The alternative is to go with aws `PCA`, which requires more complex configuration.